# Threat on/to/for

Tags: prepositions, syntactic-analysis, construction

As I was writing a sentence, it struck me that I am not all that quite sure about the noun 'threat', and how a sentence using the words 'threat' and 'cause' can be constructed. For instance:

> "Considering the threat that the A is causing on/to/for the B..."

Firstly, what would be the right preposition to use in that context? Secondly, how would you reconstruct the sentence above using the words 'threat' and 'cause' in the same context?

Comment: Something _is_ a threat _to_ something else. You don't need to say 'causing a threat'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threats are typically "posed". A threat is the **potential** for some outcome, not an outcome itself. Also, it's a noun so you wouldn't say that a threat is "caused":

"Considering the threat that A poses to the B..."

...or if the threat isn't very specific you could say:

"Considering the threat that A represents to B..."

Either way, there is a threat **to** B. A either **poses** the threat, or the existence of A **represents** a threat.

Comment: This was very insightful.